# vk api python wall.get

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, словари

Прошу подсказать , хочу собрать кол-во записей со стены в вк , с помощтю vk api

```
rs = vk.method('wall.get', {
          'owner_id': owner_id
,"type": "text",

          'count':1
      })
```

приходит словарь следующего вида :

```
[{u'attachments': [{u'photo': {u'access_key': u'21056d213f1c2d2d71',
     u'album_id': -7,
     u'date': 1501688727,
     u'height': 438,
     u'id': 456239202,
     u'owner_id': -142538016,
     u'photo_130': u'https://pp.userapi.com/c638329/v638329561/57ef4/SOC0CP8A0ds.jpg',
     u'photo_604': u'https://pp.userapi.com/c638329/v638329561/57ef5/8fc4dhhgwtI.jpg',
     u'photo_75': u'https://pp.userapi.com/c638329/v638329561/57ef3/enpGwhRr0_Y.jpg',
     u'post_id': 1224,
     u'text': u'',
     u'user_id': 100,
     u'width': 604},
    u'type': u'photo'}],...
type (rs)
Out[73]: dict

len (rs)
Out[74]: 2
```

хочу достать только кол-во постов ,например , на ум приходят только регулярные выражения , но наверняка можно как то отправить запрос ,чтобы получить только то что мне нужно. Прошу помочь .

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/get_full_wall.py) то, что вы ищете.

А вообще лучше смотрите [сюда](https://github.com/python273/vk_api) по вопросам api. Там и примеры есть)

Чтобы достать `post_id` каждого поста попробуйте что-нибудь такое :

```
wall = tools.get_all('wall.get', 100, {'owner_id': 1})
for post in wall['items']:
    print(post['id'])
```

Вот [тут](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get) находится описание работы `wall.get` там видно как получаются данные и тд.

Comment: я получаем ответ нормальный , просто он в dictionary и я не знаю , как достать только post_id, не прибегая к re . Вот суть вопроса , то что вы предлагаете ,возвразает то же самое. ну те дальше я хочу получить комменты к записям и не знаю , как их распарсить из этого словаря

Comment: Читайте, что написали, иногда трудно это понять)

Comment: сорри с телефона

Comment: я получаю нормальный ответ , просто он в словаре с кучей полей , мне например , нужен только текст комментария к посту , я могу только привести лист внутри словаря к строке  и регулярным выражением вытянуть коммент , но это криво и долго . Как правильно отправлять запрос чтобы получить только комменты к посту , например.

Comment: Если что, то я дописал ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вы вставили только малую часть пришедшего запроса, причем я не до конца понимаю, чего он так искажен. Используйте тот же `wall.get`, в первом же массиве `response->count` будет количество записей. Можете использовать библиотеку `VK` для `Python`. Там нужные методы сразу есть.

Ссылка на документацию с примером работы: [тут](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get)